# compiling quickfix on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, quickfix, autoreconf

I have been trying to compile quickfix on a Solaris 10 box. however when I try to run the `bootstrap` it gives a large number of warnings of the form ' warning: underquoted definition of AM_PATH_AUDIOFILE' before failing with:

```
aclocal: macro `_LT_DECL_SED' required but not defined
aclocal: macro `_LT_FUNC_STRIPNAME_CNF' required but not defined
configure.ac: 92: macro `AM_PATH_XML2' not found in library'
```

I'm fairly certain this is a path issue, if I run `aclocal` it fails the same way with AM_PATH_XML2 not found, but if I run `aclocal -I /usr/local/share/aclocal/` it suceedes, allbeit with the underquoted definition warnings that I'm assuming can be ignored. For some reason Solaris seems to put libxml.m4 in /usr/local/share/aclocal rather than where most of the other .m4 files are.

How can I pass this path to autoreconf that is called by `bootstrap` ? Running autoreconf with the include path does not work.

Comment: It may be the automake you're running is too old.  What version is it?

Comment: autoreconf --version gives autoreconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.59

Comment: That seems to be about a decade old.  Try a newer one if you can.  2.69 seems current (even though it came out two years ago).

Comment: OK. tried with version 2.68 that made absolutely no difference  the AM_PATH_XML2 issue will go away with symlinking - this is a path issue that I'd rather solve. the other two macro issues I can't solve though

Comment: And which version of automake?  This thread says 1.11 fixes the macro issues you have (at least for the poster): http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2011-05/0286.html

Comment: automake is 1.11 Updated m4 which was a problem, now it's failing with `configure.ac:19: error: Autoconf version 2.62 or higher is required` but autoconf --version gives autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there

The trouble was versions of packages, in particular m4 was too old, but it seems that unless m4 is updated before autoconf, autom4te calls a version of m4 that is too old causing trouble. Reapplying the autoconf package after applying the m4 package solved this.

**EDIT**

the list of packages I had to install to get this to compile
libtools
m4
autom4te
sed (obviously this was installed, but libtools was expecting in usr/local/bin not usr/bin. Without installing this gmake launches 7000 copies of libtools which seems to have the path of sed hard coded until fork fails) perl (again usr/local/bin vs usr/bin after that just the issue of exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Also both bootstrap and configure needed to be re-run after installing sed, or gmake launched 7000 copies of libtools

after configure edit the makefile and remove the flag `-Wno-unused-private-field` and gmake actually works

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the [Using autoreconf to Update configure Scripts](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html) section of the automake manual, you can specify flags to pass to `aclocal` by using the `ACLOCAL` environment variable, such as

```
env ACLOCAL='aclocal -I /usr/local/share/aclocal/' autoreconf
```